# Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError) from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in` report'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in` handle_exception'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:228:in `initialize_from_file': [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56). (RuntimeError) from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in` open'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '

i am trying to follow create a messaging app but this keeps popping each time i run pod init on the directory. i have uninstalled and reinstalled cocoapods to no avail and every answer i have seen doesn't address the issue. i am using an xcode 14.2 and the asnwers seems outdated. please i need a clear response